# elasticsearch search query for exact match not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using query_string for search. Searching is working fine but its getting all records with small letters and capital letters match.But i want to exact match with case sensitive?
For example :
Search field : "title"
Current output :

1. title
2. Title
3. TITLE,

I want to only first(title). How to resolved this issue.

My code in java :

QueryBuilder qbString=null;

qbString=QueryBuilders.queryString("title").field("field_name");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your mappings / text processing so tokens are indexed without being lowercased.

The "standard"-analyzer lowercases (and removes stopwords).

Here's an example that shows how to configure an analyzer and a mapping to achieve this: https://www.found.no/play/gist/7464654

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have resolved this issue by setting whitespace analyzer instead of default analyzer. Earlier i was using schema less mapping for documents.

Answer (score 0):

With Version 5 + on ElasticSearch there is no concept of analyzed and not analyzed for index, its driven by type !

String data type is deprecated and is replaced with text and keyword, so if your data type is text it will behave like string and can be analyzed and tokenized.

But if the data type is defined as keyword then automatically its NOT analyzed, and return full exact match.

SO you should remember to mark the type as keyword when you want to do exact match with case sensitive.

code example below for creating index with this definition:

```
PUT testindex
{
    "mappings": {
      "original": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "APPLICATION": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "exact": {"type": "keyword"}
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "exact": {"type": "keyword"}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```